# "textAlignVertical" is not a valid style property

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error saying "textAlignVertical" is not a valid style property when attempting to use the 'textAlignVertical' style on a Text element. I've checked the documentation and it says I should be able to use this style property: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Try to give `alignItems: 'center'` to a parent of a child you want to vertically center

Comment: thanks for your help @Cherniv

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `textAlignVertical` style is an Android-only property. If you are developing on iOS, try using the flexbox alignment property `alignItems: center` instead.

It also appears that the `textAlignVertical` property was moved from `TextInput` properties to the `Text` element styles only [three days ago](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/4481), and is going to be released in React Native 0.19.

I am not sure how the React Native documentation is generated, but based on my reading of this [commit diff](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f453e14c8f91d00a8205e6bb06094c85281b38be), the documentation appears to be ahead of the latest released version.

Comment: Not sure I understand the solution, `alignItems: center` ( + `flex: 1`) doesn't seem to work (testing on iOS). Maybe outdated?

Comment: I am using version `0.50.3` but `textAlignVertical ` not working.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you might find that alignItems won't work well -- I saw that an icon that I was using disappeared entirely. I instead just added an `alignSelf: 'center'` to the styling on the text itself (rather than the parent like you need to do with alignItems) and it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For `textAlignVertical` to work properly, add lineHeight prop instead of height for ios

```
height: phoneWidth * 0.09, // for android
lineHeight: phoneWidth * 0.09, // for ios
```

Answer (score 0):

The line height solution worked for me. I am writing this post to explicitly show how to set the line height by platform:

```
yourComponent: {
    width: 44, height: 44,
    ...Platform.select({
        ios: {
            lineHeight: 44
        },
        android: {}
    }),
    textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center',
}
```

It's important that your and height and line height are the same and that you do it by platform.

It's important to note that I also have this component nested in a view with alignItems set to center.

I just wanted to explicitly write this code out as I had to piece it together from a few posts and this should make it easier if someone is looking for a quick copy/paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

`textAlignVertical: 'top'` (Work for Android)

`alignSelf: 'flex-start'` (work for iOS)

So give them both properties if you are building your app for both Android and iOS.

**Like:**

```
style={{textAlignVertical: 'top', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

textAlignVertical only works for android use **multiline** for ios

```
<TextInput 
    height={32}
    textAlignVertical='top' // for android
    multiline // for ios
 />
```