# Align text vertically to bottom in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx, text-align

I want to align text to the bottom right of a view. I have aligned the text to the right using

`textAlign:'center'`

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text vertical align in react native (using nativebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337469/text-vertical-align-in-react-native-using-nativebase)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/rude-soylent)**

[image]

Here is how you can align your `Text` wherever you want with ease:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10, right: 10 }}>
          <Text>Bottom Right</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 10, left: 10 }}>
          <Text>Bottom Left</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, right: 10 }}>
          <Text>Top Right</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 10 }}>
          <Text>Top Left</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  card: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 5,
  },
});
```