# How can I implement Text which will support styles object in this reusable component?

Tags: properties, react-native, react-native-ios, react-proptypes

I've found this small library on github. I would like to make some changes on it. How can I add a text that supports style object inside the radio button (this component)? So  when use it on the other screens can implement any text inside it and change the default styles. At the moment it doesn't include even default text implementation. Here is the code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 0.7
const DEFAULT_OUTER_BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER = 0.2

export default class RadioButton extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.number,
    innerColor: PropTypes.string,
    outerColor: PropTypes.string,
    isSelected: PropTypes.bool,
    onPress: PropTypes.func
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    size: 35,
    innerColor: 'dodgerblue',
    outerColor: 'dodgerblue',
    isSelected: false,
    onPress: () => null
  }

  render () {
    const { size, innerColor, outerColor, isSelected, onPress } = this.props
    const outerStyle = {
      borderColor: outerColor,
      width: size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER,
      height: size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER,
      borderRadius: (size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER) / 2,
      borderWidth: size * DEFAULT_OUTER_BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER
    }

    const innerStyle = {
      width: size,
      height: size,
      borderRadius: size / 2,
      backgroundColor: innerColor
    }

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.radio, outerStyle]} onPress={onPress}>
        {isSelected ? <View style={innerStyle} {...this.props} /> : null}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radio: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
})
```

How can I implement that new feature that was described in the above?

Comment: What you have there should work if you would merge those two style objects: `combinedStyles = Object.assign({}, styles.radio, outerStyle)` and then use it  `<TouchableOpacity style={combinedStyles} >`.

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to make it works step by step.

firstly, code:

```js
/// 1) Make a composition component
export default class RadioButtonText extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    /// 2) Make all RadioButton props as this classes' props
    ...RadioButton.propTypes,

    /// 3) Two new props, one for string of text, one for text style.
    text: PropTypes.string,
    textStyle: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.object,
        PropTypes.number,
    ]),
  }

  static defaultProps = {
      ...RadioButton.defaultProps,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <!-- 4) Pass every props into RadioButton -->
        <RadioButton {...this.props} />
        <!-- 5) Apply text string, and style -->
        <Text style={this.props.textStyle}>{this.props.text}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

### Steps:

1. Make a composition component.

Make a new component except of modify open source, for your easier control and understand. The base idea is: Left side as `<RadioButton />`, Right side as `<Text />`, everything looks good.

2. Make all `<RadioButton />` props as this classes' props

So we can pass-in props from new component `<RadioButtonText />` into `<RadioButton />`, for every props such as `size`, `innerColor`, `outerColor`.

3. Two new props, one for string of text, one for text style.

That is all you need for your requirement. Although these two props will pass into `<RadioButton />` too, it doesn't matter at all (no effect).

4. Pass every props into `<RadioButton />`
5. Apply text string, and style

---

### Usage:

```js
<RadioButtonText
  {/* props for RadioButton */}
  size={10}
  isSelected={false}
  {/* props for RadioButtonText */}
  text='Radio Text!'
  textStyle={{fontSize: 18}}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. But what if I want to implement this text inside the button (in the center of the button)? I tried it yesterday and it looked like a destroyed.

Comment: I add another one. see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to modify it, this could helps.

`<Text />` added inside the `<RadioButton />`.

See comment below.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 0.7
const DEFAULT_OUTER_BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER = 0.2

export default class RadioButton extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.number,
    innerColor: PropTypes.string,
    outerColor: PropTypes.string,
    isSelected: PropTypes.bool,
    onPress: PropTypes.func,

    /// 1) Added new props
    text: PropTypes.string,
    textStyle: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.object,
        PropTypes.number,
    ]),
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    size: 35,
    innerColor: 'dodgerblue',
    outerColor: 'dodgerblue',
    isSelected: false,
    onPress: () => null
  }

  render () {
    const { size, innerColor, outerColor, isSelected, onPress } = this.props
    const outerStyle = {
      borderColor: outerColor,
      width: size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER,
      height: size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER,
      borderRadius: (size + size * DEFAULT_SIZE_MULTIPLIER) / 2,
      borderWidth: size * DEFAULT_OUTER_BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER
    }

    const innerStyle = {
      width: size,
      height: size,
      borderRadius: size / 2,
      backgroundColor: innerColor
    }

    /// 2) Style for unselected radio - was null in open source
    const innerStyleUnselected = {
        ...innerStyle,
        backgroundColor: transparent,
    }

    /// 3) Put text in. Make sure inner View not null
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.radio, outerStyle]} onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={isSelected ? innerStyle : innerStyleUnselected}>
            <Text style={this.props.textStyle}>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radio: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
})
```

Comment: @Artyom that would be another problem about styling. My answer is for how to modify open source code, to add `<Text />` in. That could be another big topic if we talk about how to align your text in to your desire place.

Comment: for example, `textAlignVertical` is useful style to align your text. But sadly it's *Android Only*. If you want to make it works for iOS also, there's already many other answers out there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969848/textalignvertical-is-not-a-valid-style-property