# How to align Icon vertically in IOS devices?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to align this options icon inside the TouchableHighlight in **IOS** application in **react-native** but when I implement it is not using **textAlignVerticle** property as it is android only property. How I can get the alternative which works both in android and IOS?

```js
<TouchableHighlight  
                style={[{position: 'absolute', bottom: 20, zIndex:999999, right: 155, borderRadius: 25}, (this.state.searchList)? { backgroundColor: 'red' }: {backgroundColor: 'black'}]}
                onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchSetting')}
            >
  <Icon name="options" style={{height: 50, width: 50, color: 'white', textAlign: 'center', textAlignVertical: 'center'}} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969848/textalignvertical-is-not-a-valid-style-property

Answer (score 0):

A component of react native is using the flexbox algorithm (very same with CSS Flexbox). So you can put any child component to the vertically or horizontally align using `justifyContent` and `alignItems` in parent component. Both `justifyContent` and `alignItems` are depends on `flexDirection`. The default `flexDirection` is `column` in react native.

#### In `flexDirection: 'row';`

You can align child component to the vertically for `justifyContent` and horizontally for `alignItems` in parent component.

Try with below code:

```
<TouchableHighlight  
  style={[
    { 
      position: 'absolute', 
      bottom: 20, 
      zIndex:999999, 
      right: 155, 
      borderRadius: 25,
      backgroundColor: '#0000ff'
     }
  ]}>

  <View 
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
    <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={20} color={'#FFF'} />
  </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I don't know what icon component are you using. I'm using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons). So I don't need to set `width` and `height` in style props of icon component for icon size.